# Will invalidating a form invalidate all the controls inside it?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE3. Will invalidating a form invalidate all the controls inside it? Based on my test, it will not. But based my understanding, since a form need to be invalidated, all its controls should also be, too.

**Update**

Actually I try Repaint, Update, Invalidate for the form, and find all of them will not cause the control inside it to be repainted, updated or invalidated. I must invoke the function for the corresponding control to do the task.

Comment: Calling `Invalidate` on the form does not invalidate the controls on the form, as it is not needed. Also `invalidate` doesn't immediately start a `paint` cycle, it just marks the form "dirty", that is "in need to be repainted". This will trigger the paint cycle when the message que becomes empty, and paint the form and any controls on it. That is why there is no need to invalidate the components on the form.

Comment: As far as I can see from the source, controls of a form having csParentBackground control style are invalidated with the form if style services are enabled. Frames and panels are examples..

Comment: The answer conflicts with your claims. I suggest you provide a [MCVE]

Comment: (1) When you tested this, did you consider the fundamental difference between windowed controls and graphic controls? (2) As @TomBrunberg wrote, please note that `Invalidate` simply sets the "needs to be repainted" flag which will cause a `WM_PAINT` message to be generated at a later time (maybe a millisecond or two later). `Update` will immediately repaint any invalidated region. `Repaint` or `Refresh` immediately repaints (so, essentially, `Repaint = Invalidate + Update`). Normally one only invalidates.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that invalidating the form will not, eventually, cause the controls inside it to be repainted? Please provide the code that demonstrates this.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: I did a quick test with a new VCL application (Delphi 10.4) and put my own windowed button control on it. Doing `Invalidate` on the form doesn't invalidate the button.

Comment: Oh, @Andreas I was actually asking OP (hence no adressee) to provide an example that demonstrates the **will not, eventually, cause the controls to be painted**. Note the *eventually*.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: I got that! :) I just wanted to share the results of my 30-second experiment (indicating that it probably isn't hard to come up with such an example).

Comment: Normally painting validated controls shouldn't result with effective drawing, I wouldn't be surprised if coming up with a test case is not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Typically yes, I believe so.

Per MSDN - [Child Window Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/child-window-update-region):

> A child window's update and visible regions are affected by the child's parent window; this is not true for windows of other styles. **The system often sets the child window's update region when it sets the parent window's update region, causing the child window to receive WM_PAINT messages when the parent window receives them.** The system limits the location of the child window's visible region to within the client area of the parent window and clips any portion of the child window moved outside the parent window.
>
> **The system sets the update region for a child window whenever part of the parent window's update region includes a portion of the child window.** In such cases, the system first sends a WM_PAINT message to the parent window and then sends a message to the child window, allowing the child to restore any portions of the window that the parent may have drawn over.
>
> ...
>
> **An application can prevent a child window's update region from being set when the parent window's is set by specifying the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style when creating the parent window. When this style is set, the system excludes the child windows from the parent's visible region and therefore ignores any portion of the update region that may contain the child windows.** When the application paints in the parent window, any drawing that would cover the child window is clipped, making a subsequent WM_PAINT message to the child window unnecessary.

If a VCL `TWinControl` has the `csAcceptsControls` flag set in its `ControlStyle` property, it will enable the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on its own `HWND`.  However, a `TForm` (which is a `TWinControl` descendant) does not have `csAcceptsControls` enabled by default, which means its child controls are not excluded from being invalidated when the `TForm`'s window is invalidated.

Various container-like controls enable `csAcceptsControls` for themselves by default.  Such as `TGroupBox`, `TPanel`, `TControlBar`, etc.  But not `TForm`.

Comment: A default VCL form has csAcceptsControls set in TCustomForm.InitializeNewForm, consequently a form's window has ws_clipchildren set.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `TCustomForm.InitializeNewForm()` exists in FMX, but not in VCL. I was looking at the VCL source when I wrote my answer. And in VCL, I see no code that enables `csAcceptsControls` on a `TForm` by default.

Comment: Perhaps the design has changed then. I'm looking at XE2 source, TCustomForm.InitializeNewForm is at line 3586 in Vcl.Forms.pas.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I was looking at XE3. I’ll look at XE2 tomorrow.